# How to align these columns of different divs?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How may I align the items of these differet divs?

I'm trying to align the header of each column to the items of the divs below, could you please help me to aligns these?

`row-header-course` with `course-name`

`row-header-progress` with `course-progress`

`row-header-remaining` with `course-remaining`

`row-header-timestamp` with `course-timestamp`

All aligned left.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="row historico">

        <div class="row row-header col-md-12">
            <div class="row-header-course col-md-4">Curso</div>
            <div class="row-header-progress col-md-2">Progresso</div>
            <div class="row-header-remaining col-md-2">Faltam</div>
            <div class="row-header-timestamp col-md-2">Visto por último</div>
            <div class="row-header-remove col-md-2">Remover</div>
        </div>

            <div class="row-history col-md-12">
                <div class="course-row row">
                    <div class="course-name col-md-4">
                        <i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        <a href="https://www.xxx.com.br/curso-teste-4">Curso Teste 4</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="course-progress col-md-2">
                        <div class="course-progress-bar-wrapper col-md-8">
                            <div class="course-progress-bar" style="width: 100%;">&nbsp;</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="course-progress-percent col-md-4">100%</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="course-remaining col-md-2">Completo</div>
                    <div class="course-timestamp col-md-2">20 horas atrás</div>
                    <div class="course-remove col-md-2"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                </div> <!--  .course-row -->
                <div class="unit-row">

                    <div class="row single-unit">
                        <div class="unit-name col-md-4">
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            Curso Teste 4 - Unidade 2
                        </div>
                        <div class="unit-nbsp col-md-4">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="unit-timestamp col-md-2">20 horas atrás</div>
                    <div class="unit-remove col-md-2"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                    </div>

                </div> <!--  .unit-row -->
            </div> <!--  .row-history -->

</div>
```

EDIT:

This is how it's now:
[image]

This is how I want to be:
[image: enter code here]

Comment: can you attach image of layout how it should be?

Comment: @shiva, I've edited the question and added what you requested.

Comment: I posted the answer and its same what you looking for, you need to fallow the same gird structure. let me know if any difficulties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it with:

```
.course-progress, .course-remaining, .course-timestamp, .course-remove, .unit-nbsp, .unit-timestamp, .unit-remove {
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code structure you need to fallow. let me know if this did't help you. I have done for only 2 columns right now

and here is working js fiddel link : https://jsfiddle.net/tdxje0su/1/

```
                <div class="row row-header col-md-12">
                    <div class="row-header-course col-md-6">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            Curso
                        </div>
                        <div class="course-name col-md-12">
                            <i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            <a href="https://www.xxx.com.br/curso-teste-4">Curso Teste 4</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row-header-progress col-md-2">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            Progresso
                        </div>
                        <div class="course-progress col-md-12">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="course-progress-percent col-md-12">100%</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row-header-remaining col-md-2">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            Faltam
                        </div>
                        <div class="course-remaining col-md-12">Completo</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row-header-timestamp col-md-2">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            Visto por último
                        </div>
                        <div class="course-timestamp col-md-12">19 horas atrás</div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div> <!-- .historico -->
```

Comment: I got what you are trying to do here, to make all divs 100% inside the `col-md` but I guess that would have a better solution because you are basically putting a `col-md-12` inside a `col-md-12`

Comment: It might have another solution involving the class `row` on the parent `div`

Comment: thanks but I got it with `padding: 0 !important;` of the cells. Cheers! +1